# Showing and hiding divs using CSS @media query not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries, display

When my browser is at greater than 300px width, my `<div id="div1">` is hidden with `display: none`.  However, if the browser screen is less than 300px width, it should be showing with `display: inline-block`.

Why isn't my `<div id="div1">` showing up and displaying on-screen after I adjust the width of the browser less than 300px in my code below:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
  #div1 { display: inline-block;}
}

#div1 { display: none; }
```

```html
<!--My HTML-->
<div>
  Some content 1
</div>
<div id="div1">
  Some Content 2
</div>
<div>
  Some content 3
</div>
```

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1no0csL/1/) offers a small results window where you can adjust the width of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because css is read from top to bottom. The rule that is set last, is the one that will be executed, so replace position of media query

```css
#div1 { display: none; }
@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
  #div1 { display: inline-block;}
}
```

```html
<!--My HTML-->
<div>
  Some content 1
</div>
<div id="div1">
  Some Content 2
</div>
<div>
  Some content 3
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer.  I wasn't aware CSS was read in that way prior.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to declare your `display: none;` first, CSS runs from top to bottom:

```
#div1 { 
  display: none; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  #div1 {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code as shown below:

```
#div1 { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
  #div1 { display: inline-block;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the order of your cascaded styles

NB display none is to be over-ridden with display so that it will display at all

```
#div1 { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
  #div1 { display: inline-block;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@media` queries do not change specificity. At all. They just either apply the code or ignore it, depending on the provided condition.

Therefore, your code translates into:

```
#div1 { display: inline-block;}
#div1 { display: none; }
```

below `width: 300px`

and into

```
#div1 { display: none; }
```

above it.

You need to place the `@media` last if the specificity of the selectors remains the same.

```css
#div1 { display: none; }

@media (max-width: 300px){
  #div1 { display: inline-block;}
}
```

```html
<div>
  Some content 1
</div>
<div id="div1">
  Some Content 2 - only visible up to max-width:300px
</div>
<div>
  Some content 3
</div>
```